# orden de complejidad java

Tags: java, array, complejidad

tenia que hacer un un algoritmo que devuelva los promedios de un array bidimensional, lo cual ya lo tengo hecho pero ademas de eso tengo que identificar su orden de complejidad y con eso estoy muy perdida, si me puden ayudar lo agradeceria o al menos si me pasan un video que explique eso tambien me ayudaria, vi varios pero hacen unas cuentas muy complejas

yo estuve viendo el tiempo que tardaba el algoritmo con el codigo  "System.currentTimeMillis" y su tiempo siempre daba alrededor de 10. por lo que pienso creo que es constante porque no depende de n pero como dije no se bien como diferenciar y en los videos que vi nunca usan el currentTime asi que no se que pensar

les dejo el codigo

```
public static float[] matriz(float[][] array) {      
    float[] promedios = new float[array.length];     
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {           
        float suma = 0;          
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {              
            suma += array[i][j];
        }           
        float promedio = suma / array.length;          
        promedios[i] = promedio;
    }      
    return promedios;
}
```

`

Comment: un ciclo `for` normal tiene un complejidad de `O(n)`, a partir de ahí ya tienes todo

Comment: Complejidad de tiempo? Busca Big-O y no necesitas comprobarlo empíricamente. Como te indica Christian en el otro comentario, este tipo de análisis parte de la estructura del código para _predecir_ su comportamiento esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introducción

> pero ademas de eso tengo que identificar su orden de complejidad y con eso estoy muy perdida

Cuando se habla de **orden de complejidad** o **complejidad de un algoritmo** se hace referencia a la [Teoría de la complejidad computacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_la_complejidad_computacional) que básicamente es una rama de la informática que se centra en clasificar **problemas computacionales** de acuerdo a la dificultad de cada cual.

Uno de los campos de la *Teoría de la complejidad computacional* es el [Análisis de algoritmos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lisis_de_algoritmos) que se basa en proveer **estimaciones teóricas** para los **recursos** que necesita cualquier algoritmo que resuelva un problema computacional dado.

Cuando hablamos de **recursos**, en general, se  habla del recurso de tiempo y memoria computacional.

Teniendo en claro todo esto...

---

> yo estuve viendo el tiempo que tardaba el algoritmo con el codigo "System.currentTimeMillis" y su tiempo siempre daba alrededor de 10

Si bien esta podría ser una forma de calcular cuánto tarda específicamente tu algoritmo en resolver el problema para una entrada determinada (Con entrada me refiero al tamaño del arreglo bidimensional o matriz) no es la forma en la que se calcula el orden de complejidad.

Como dijimos anteriormente

> El Análisis de algoritmos se basa en proveer **estimaciones teóricas**

Como son estimaciones teóricas, el cálculo del orden de complejidad va a estar expresado como una función que depende de la entrada (`O(log(n))` para la búsqueda binaria por ejemplo), y no como un valor fijo (`10` como comentaste en tu pregunta).

Esto último es así porque, recordando lo expuesto en el principio, estamos tratando de **clasificar** problemas computacionales de acuerdo a su dificultad.

Por lo tanto, al clasificar tu algoritmo y calcular su complejidad (temporal) vas a determinar qué clase de algoritmo es. Aquí puedes ver cuáles son esas [clases de complejidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_temporal#Tabla_de_complejidades_temporales_comunes)

---

### Identificando el orden de complejidad

Por último, habiendo explicado un poco de qué se trata esto de "identificar su orden de complejidad" podemos proceder brevemente a calcular el orden de complejidad de tu algoritmo:

Cosas a tener en cuenta para calcular la complejidad temporal:

1. La complejidad temporal se estima comúnmente contando el **número de operaciones elementales** realizadas por el algoritmo, suponiendo que cada operación elemental requiere una cantidad fija de tiempo.
2. Dado que el tiempo de ejecución de un algoritmo puede variar entre diferentes entradas del mismo tamaño, comúnmente se considera la complejidad temporal del **peor caso.**
3. La complejidad temporal se expresa como una función del tamaño de la entrada.
4. Dado que esta función es generalmente difícil de calcular exactamente, uno comúnmente se enfoca en el **comportamiento** de la complejidad cuando aumenta el tamaño de entrada, es decir, el comportamiento asintótico de la complejidad (Es decir, cuando la entrada tiende a ser muy grande).
5. La complejidad temporal se expresa comúnmente usando la notación [O grande](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cota_superior_asint%C3%B3tica).

Teniendo en cuenta todo esto, procedemos a identificar la complejidad temporal de tu algoritmo (De una forma bastante simplificada):

```java
1 public static float[] matriz(float[][] array) {      
2    float[] promedios = new float[array.length]; // 1 operación elemental
3    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // En un bucle se calcula el cuerpo del mismo por la cantidad de iteraciones           
4        float suma = 0; // 1 operación elemental
5        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) { // Lo mismo con este bucle              
6            suma += array[i][j]; // 1 operación elemental (son mas operaciones elem. pero para simplificar diremos que es 1)
7        }           
8        float promedio = suma / array.length; // 1 op. elem.
9        promedios[i] = promedio; // 1 op. elem.
10    }      
11    return promedios;
}
```

Entonces, contando las operaciones elementales (OE) tenemos (Para cada línea en el código):

- En la línea 2 tenemos `1 OE`
- En la línea 3 tenemos el bucle for con otro bucle for anidado, por lo tanto las operaciones elementales serían:
  `N` x ( `1 OE` + `N` x (`1 OE`) + `1 OE` + `1 OE`)

(Siendo `N` el ancho de la matriz)

Para concluir, sumamos todas las operaciones elementales:

> `1 OE` + `N` x (`3 OE` + `N`)

Simplificando tenemos (Sacándole `OE`):

> `1` + `3`x`N` + `N^2` // Los términos que no dependen de N generalmente no se toman en cuenta

Por último, podemos clasificar esta función según la [Tabla de complejidades temporales comunes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complejidad_temporal#Tabla_de_complejidades_temporales_comunes) y podremos concluir que el algoritmo en cuestión tiene un orden de tiempo cuadrático, con una notación: `O(N^2)`

Espero que te haya aclarado un poco. Por favor no dudes en agregar un comentario si crees que puedo mejorar mi respuesta.

Comment: Guau, tremenda explicación! Tienes mi +1. Si me permites, me gustaría agregar un par de puntos: Motivos por los que no se usa el tiempo para medir (entre otros): 1)Si tu CPU es multi hilo es probable que tengas que dividir la carga por hilo y computar la carga de los mismos. 2)Dependeria de que muestra de datos uses y el ejercicio que le requieras, (ejemplo->) no es lo mismo un for que un short. Otra cosa: Existen analizadores de código que realizan la función de precisar el coste, incluso algunos te recomiendan reformulaciones de código

Comment: Gracias, muy buenos tus puntos añadidos. Te parece que la respuesta sería más completa con esos puntos? Si es así avísame. Saludos

Comment: Bueno, es algo que comenta el OP y por eso pensé en añadirlo. Realmente tu explicación es muy buena (quizá algo compleja para los principiantes, pero está bien), así que dejo a tu juicio lo que quieras hacer.